# Drupal Views Relationship problem using nodes and profiles

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I'm using nodes as profiles so I dont think standard Views relationships are working, can you advise if this is the case?

I have users profile nodes with a CCK field called "field_sports" and a CCK field for a content type of events called "field_sport".  I only want the view to display sports that match in these two fields.  Seems like a simple operation but it's kicking my butt right now, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify two things:  1. 'nodes as profiles' - do you mean via the 'content profile' module?  2. The relation of the two CCK fields are not clear - what type are they, are they single or multi valued and is one of them a nodereference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in the views issue queue.

This is currently not possible with clicking in the ui.

Alternative you can write your own filter handler, but this isn't that easy.